# if Exception happened in authorization filter in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In my recent interview, interviewer asked the question like

if there is exception occurred in authorization filter how the program flow occur ? whether it will go to exception filter directly or else go by sequentially in action filter then result filter and exception filter.

i said it will go to exception filter directly. but interviewer is not fine with my answer. any suggestions?

I knew mvc filters executed order.

1.Authorization 2.Action 3. Result 4.Exception  we can also set the order for each filter.

But if there is exception occur in any one of above filters what happens next ? whether it will go directly to exception filter skipping the result filter or else it will go sequentially.

i googled but didn't get clear idea. please direct me to correct links without down-voting.

Comment: Your answer is totally correct. Program flow will come to the exception filter if any exception occurred in any other filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the interviewer may have been looking for an answer such that you use an override on the exception

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{ 
  Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
  //Logging the Exception
  filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;


  var Result = this.View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(exception,
   filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
   filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()));

  filterContext.Result = Result;

 }
```

Comment: what is the use of overriding the exception.please provide full details

Comment: this will get called before any local try catch and sit's at application level as opposed to method level